# How to dynamically add thead, tr, th and td to table using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to generate a table using data from a webAPI controller. I have gotten that part working but I am having trouble using jQuery to dynamically add table headers and rows.

I have tried various methods but they all do not return the result i need.

This is my HTML code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4" id="table" >

    </div>
    <div class="col-8">
        <div class="row">


            <div class="col-12" id="graph">
                <p class="text-center">Select an expiation description to continue...</p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to add the dynamic table into the div id="table".

This is the latest bit of code that I have tried so far:

```
<script>



        $('<h2>').addClass('text-center').text('Speeding Category by Year').appendTo('#table');
        var $mainTable = $('<table>').addClass('table table-striped table-hover');
        $('<thead>').appendTo($mainTable);
        $($mainTable.find('thead')).append('<tr></tr>');
        $($mainTable.find('thead tr')).append('<th class="text-left">Speeding Category</th> <th class="text-right">Tickets Issued</th>')


        var array = $.ajax({
            url: "/api/ExpiationsWebAPI",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",                       
            success: function () { alert("Sucess"); },            
            timeout: 10000

        });

        var year = 0;
        i = 1;
        array.done(function (data) {
            $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
                if (obj.year != year) {

                    year = obj.year
                    $('<thead>').appendTo($mainTable);
                    $('<tr>').appendTo($mainTable.find('thead').eq(i));
                    $('<th>').text(obj.year).addClass('table-info text-center').attr('colspan', '3').appendTo($mainTable.find('.year' + obj.year));    
                    i++;

                }
            })

        })

        $mainTable.appendTo('#table');


    </script>
```

this is what that piece of code renders

[Current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dkb6K.png)

This is what im trying to achieve:

[The result i am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlctI.png)

Comment: My bad, i have added a picture of the current html code that is being rendered

Comment: haha all good! i got confused my self so i had to test using a html validator.

Comment: see [**This example**](https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/b1x6fay2/22/) .. If you didn't understand anything in the fiddle let me know